# Setting NSDocument as delegate of NSMenu

Tags: cocoa, delegates, nsdocument

I have a menu item whose state should depend on whichever `NSDocument` is open.  From my understanding, to make its state change dynamically I should use the `NSMenu` delegate method `menuNeedsUpdate:`.

It seems like I would want to have the menu's delegate be the First Responder in `MainMenu.xib`.  However, Interface Builder won't let me set it as the Main Menu's delegate.  How can I make a delegate which will be able to access the currently active document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I generally make such changes in the [`validateMenuItem:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSMenuValidation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) method being called before the menu is shown. The receiver of the action is asked whether the item is to be enabled or not. But you can do pretty much any change there. Since 10.5 it is also safe to add and remove items during such a call.